# I am unable to find attribute values from JSON data in python

Tags: python, json, parsing

I want to find `id` and `options` in this JSON data.
Here's What I did so far.

```
data = """
      "list": null,
      "promotionID": "",
      "isFreeShippingApplicable": true,
      "html": "\n\n\n<div class=\"b-product-tile-price\">\n    \n    \n\n\n\n<span class=\"b-product-tile-price-outer\">\n    <span class=\"b-product-tile-price-item\">\n        1200 &euro;\n\n\n    </span>\n</span>\n\n</div>\n\n"
    },
    "longDescription": "<ul>\n\t<li>STYLE:&nbsp;BQ4420-100</li>\n\t<li>Laufsohle: Gummi</li>\n\t<li>Obermaterial: beschichtetes Leder, Textil</li>\n\t<li>Innenmaterial: Textil</li>\n</ul>\n",
    "shortDescription": null,
    "availability": {
      "messages": [
        "Sofort lieferbar"
      ],
      "inStockDate": null,
      "custom": {
        "code": null,
        "label": null,
        "orderable": true,
        "sizeSelectable": true,
        "badge": false

"""

find_values = json.loads(data)
id = find_values["id"]
variables = find_product_data["variables"]
print(id, variables)
```

The output is an erro but when I try to get the values of first the attribute `action`, it gets returned but not the others.

Answer (score 2):

You can't access the `id` directly, because it is nested inside another dictionary. What you have to do is get that dict first and then access the `id`.

```
find_values = json.loads(data)
product = find_values["product"]
id_value = product("id")
```

If you are working with an IDE it could help to debug your code and see how the dict is actually nested.